# Case-insensitve search using PyKeePass

Tags: python

I am using PyKeePass to programatically access a KeePass database. This code:

```
from pykeepass import PyKeePass

try:
    kp = PyKeePass("info.kdbx", password="12345")
except Exception, e:
    print "Got exception",e

lstEntry = kp.find_entries_by_notes(".*Chocolate.*",regex=True)
print lstEntry
print lstEntry[0].notes
```

prints:

```
[Entry: "Info/Chocolate (None)"]
Chocolate chips are a great invention
```

However, there is no way that I can get the result if I use "chocolate" instead of "Chocolate". I have tried the "i" modifier:

```
"/.*chocolate.*/i"
"(.*chocolate.*)i"
```

...without success. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is a regex issue, not a PyKeePass issue.

Answer (score 0):

From [the PyKeePass documentation](https://github.com/pschmitt/pykeepass/blob/master/README.rst), the syntax is:

> **find_entries_by_notes** (notes, regex=False, flags=None, tree=None, history=False, first=False)
>
> where `title`, `username`, `password`, `url`, `notes` and `path` are strings. These functions have optional `regex` boolean and `flags` string arguments, which means to interpret the string as an [XSLT style](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) regular expression with [flags](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags).

Thus, you need to use the `i-flag` like this:

```
find_entries_by_notes(".*chocolate.*", regex=True, flags="i")
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, this would not work, once you start using dict parameters you cannot continue using positional paramters. It should be something like `find_entries_by_notes(".*chocolate.*", regex=True, flags="i")`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that now the documentation has been changed and instead of `find_entries_by_notes` function, you should use `find_entries` function instead.

See: https://github.com/libkeepass/pykeepass#finding-entries

`find_entries` function has optional regex boolean and flags string arguments, which means to interpret search strings as [XSLT style](https://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html) regular expressions with [flags](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#flags).

```
find_entries(".*chocolate.*", regex=True, flags='i')
```